# How to show/hide material table footer programmatically?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there a way to show/hide the the material table footer using an `@Input()` variable? I am trying to build a custom table component which may or may not have a footer, like so

```
<my-component [showFooter]="false"></my-component>
```

The obvious thing I thought about is just putting an `*ngIf` on the `mat-footer-row` inside the component definition. But when I try to use

```
<tr *ngIf="showFooter" *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
```

or

```
<td *ngIf="showFooter" mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>{{someValue}}</td>
```

I get the following error from the compiler.

```
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with *
```

What is the correct way to implement this if I cannot achieve it using an `*ngIf`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use only one structural directive (denoted by the *) on a single element.

You can use `ng-container`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showFooter">
  <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>{{someValue}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, yelling a `matColumnDef` cannot have an empty content. So it may only work if you also define a `mat-cell` and/or a `mat-header-cell` inside this `matColumnDef`...

Comment: This answer does not work any longer, the answer that worked for me is the one by Benjamin Freitag using the `hidden` attribute

Answer (score 7):

I used the hidden-attribute, so no extra CSS is required:

```js
<tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns" [hidden]="!showFooter"></tr>
```

Comment: [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) is perfectly appropriate and may be simpler than extending the component in some cases.

Answer (score 6):

The other option using CSS and `mat-footer-row`:

```
<tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns" [style.display]="showFooter ? 'table-row' : 'none'"></tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide it with css:

```
.mat-table {

  tfoot {
    display: none;
  }

  &.footer-visible {
    tfoot {
      display: table-footer-group;
    }
  }
}
```

then inside table:

```
<table mat-table [class.footer-visible]="false">
...
```